# Java socket from tcp to udp

Tags: java, tcp, network-programming, udp, datagram

how do I get this code (tcp) to udp in java? Thanks.

```
ServerSocket servsock2 = new ServerSocket(13367);
Socket sock = servsock2.accept();
System.out.println("Client connected.");
OutputStream os = sock2.getOutputStream();
while(true){
    os.write(int_value);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following Java tutorial should get you started: [All About Datagrams](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html).

Comment: +1, for providing the answer without code, which will require @maximal to think a little.